# Could not connect mongodb with PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I have an issue.I am getting some issue while trying to connect mongodb with php. I am providing my code below.

index.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbcon/DBConnection.php';
$dbobj = new DBConnection();
$dbobj->connect();  
?>

<form method="post" name="frmlogin" id="frmlogin" action="" autocomplete="off" class="mt">
<label for="" class="text-uppercase text-sm">Username</label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="txtname" class="form-control mb">

<label for="" class="text-uppercase text-sm">Password</label>
<input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="pwd" class="form-control mb">

<div class="checkbox checkbox-circle checkbox-info">
<input id="checkbox7" type="checkbox" checked>
<label for="checkbox7">
    Keep me signed in
</label>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" name="login" id="login" type="submit" onClick="return valid();">LOGIN</button>

</form>
```

DBConnection.php:

```
class DBConnection{


  public function connect() {
        require_once 'dbcon/config.php';
        $dbname='koolfeedback';
        $con=new MongoClient('mongodb://localhost');
        $db=$con->$dbname;
        return $db;
    }
}
```

In this case while i am requesting the page its giving the below error.

```
The localhost page isn’t working

localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

When I am doing the line `$con=new MongoClient('mongodb://localhost');` as comment line its coming means there is a connection error. I need to resolve that.

I have also put the `php_mongo-1.6.8-5.6-vc11.dll` file inside xampp'ext folder and paste `extension = php_mongo-1.6.8-5.6-vc11.dll` inside php.ini-development and php.ini-production file but still getting the issue. I am accessing the mongodb using the command `mongod --dbpath C:\xampp\htdocs\KoolFeedback\database`.

Comment: Are you able to see `Mongo` in your `phpinfo()` ?

Comment: What do your errors logs say?

Comment: @JonStirling : I am not getting any error log in mongodb server while running.its only shows connections 0.

Comment: @Abbasi : I am using xampp.Where i will check this.

Comment: Try to use `echo phpinfo();`  in your `index.php` before `session_start();`

Comment: @Abbasi :Ok,I did it i am not getting any `Mongo` there.

Comment: @Abbasi : There i am getting the php version `5.4.7`.

Comment: You should get `Mongo` extension there and should be `enabled`.. Have a look at this [article](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2015/10/php-mongodb-for-xampp/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+TheGeekStuff+(The+Geek+Stuff)) to configure your `Xammp` and `Mongo` properly.